# How can I get the file content from uploadfilefield?

Tags: javascript, extjs, file-upload, extjs4.2

I am trying to get the file content from `uploadfilefield` using **ExtJS4**, but do not know how?

I have this code for `uploadfilefield`:

```
{
    xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
    buttonText : 'Upload CSV',
    buttonConfig:
    {
        icon: 'images/upload.png',
        tooltip: 
        {
            text: 'some hints',
            width: 200
        }
    },
    buttonOnly: true,
    listeners: 
    {
        'change': function(fb, v)
        {
            // v returns the filename
            // HOW CAN I GET THE FILE CONTENT?
        }
    }
}
```

I was thinking that maybe *`fb`* has the content, but **`alert(JSON.stringify(fb))`** gives me an error about *`fb`* being a circular object.

I am guessing that there has to be other way/event. Also I want to get the file content right away after pressing open on the dialog box. I cannot use submit button to do this afterwords.

**Thanks my fellow StackOverflowers ;)**

**Addendum:**

I am looking at this [**EXAMPLE**](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File) on Sencha:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Upload a Photo',
    width: 400,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    frame: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'filefield',
        name: 'photo',
        fieldLabel: 'Photo',
        labelWidth: 50,
        msgTarget: 'side',
        allowBlank: false,
        anchor: '100%',
        buttonText: 'Select Photo...'
    }],

    buttons: [{
        text: 'Upload',
        handler: function() {
            var form = this.up('form').getForm();
            if(form.isValid()){
                form.submit({
                    url: 'photo-upload.php',
                    waitMsg: 'Uploading your photo...',
                    success: function(fp, o) {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Your photo "' + o.result.file + '" has been uploaded.');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

What is being passed to 'photo-upload.php'? How this php is supposed to get the content of the file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found my answer here in `extjs file uploader folder` (modified it a little for my app)

```
$returnResponse = $_REQUEST['returnResponse'];
    sleep(1);
    if ($returnResponse != "") 
    {
        header('HTTP/1.0 '.$returnResponse.' Server status', true, $returnResponse);
        echo '{success:false, message:"File could not be uploaded to server."}}';
    } 
    else 
    {
        $file      = $_FILES['filedata-inputEl'];
        $fileName  = $file['name'];
        $fileSize  = $file['size'];
        $temp_file = $file['tmp_name'];
 // ....

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Before HTML5, there was no access to the file content until after uploading it to a server and handling it from there.  The browser was not be able to do anything with this file without first submitting the form.

**EDIT**:

From Neil McGuigan's comment above, it looks like the HTML5 FileReader API can possibly do some of the things you need.  I have never used this, but more info is available herE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/

Comment: Can you edit your answer with actual code example with simple file submission form. I just want to see how can I send the file content to a php file. No need to implement anything for php part. Just need to know the transformation part from js to php. Thnaks

Comment: You just need to do a `form.submit(params)`, and include the `url` of your php file in `params`.  See the docs on this function for more help there: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-submit.  If you need your file contents right away, you can parse them as needed in your php and send the data back to the `callback` in your `params`.